# Getting undefined method `reject' error in a Rails 3.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In a rails app view the following works fine:

```
<%= bc.items.uniq.collect{|g| g.display_name}.join(", ") %>
```

However, I am trying to collect only items that have an id that includes numbers up to and including 23. I can't seem to get the syntax right. The following produces an error.

```
<%= bc.items.uniq.collect{|g| g.display_name(false)}.join(", ").reject{g.id > 23} %>
```

Error msg:

```
undefined method `reject'
```

Can I use 'reject'?

Comment: as much as i can see you are performing a join before the reject. The join method transforms enumerables to a string while the reject method is a method of the array class. try to pass reverse the order of those two operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to put `.reject` before you `.collect` and `.join`, as you need to work with the Array of objects, `.collect` will return an array of strings from what I can infer, and `.join` will make it a string.
2. You need to make `g` the argument to the block.

This should work;

```
<%= bc.items.uniq.reject{|g| g.id > 23}.collect{|g| g.display_name(false)}.join(", ") %>
```